# Is there a way to visualize the SemanticModel in Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

In many different cases, I search for a symbol in the `SemanticModel` using Roslyn but cannot find it.

```
var sm = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
sm.GetSymbolInfo(node);
sm.GetDeclaredSymbol(node);
```

So I would like to inspect the semantic model.

- Is it possible to get the full list of types loaded in the `SemanticModel`?
- Is it possible to see everything that is available in the `SemanticModel`? Without having to search for a specific symbol.
- Is there a visual tool for visualizing the `SemanticModel`?

This would help when debugging.

#### Edit

Following Dudi Keleti's approach, this snippet is being very effective:

```
return tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodesAndSelf()
         .Where(node => node as ClassDeclarationSyntax != null || node as InterfaceDeclarationSyntax != null)
         .Select(node => new KeyValuePair<SyntaxNode, ISymbol>(node, model.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol ?? model.GetDeclaredSymbol(node)));
```

Comment: Are you interested only in symbols declared in the compilation, or also those that are just referenced?

Comment: remember, the `SemanticModel` is per `SyntaxTree`, can't imagine a sensible way of visualizing that for the whole compilation (which has multiple `SyntaxTree`s)

Comment: How are you searching for the symbol? Roslyn should always find the symbols you need assuming the program you're analyzing has no errors. Also make sure you're using `.GetDeclaredSymbol()` or `.GetSymbolInfo()` as appropriate.

Comment: Hi all and thanks for your comments.

@svick: I am interested in understanding which nodes in the syntax tree are covered by the `SemanticModel` and which are not.

@m0sa: Yes i know, my updated question should make it evident.

@JoshVarty: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about a visualizer tool, but you can do something like this:

```
static IEnumerable<ISymbol> GetTeeSymbols(SyntaxTree tree, SemanticModel model)
{
    return tree.GetRoot().
             DescendantNodesAndSelf().
             Select(node => model.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol ?? model.GetDeclaredSymbol(node)).Where(info => info != null);
}
```

You can do it as extension method on tree and send a semantic model or extension on semantic model and send an `IEnumerable<SyntaxTree>` than go over each of them and do the LINQ

I don't know if it's perfect but it give you an idea of what going on.
On my compilation its looks like this:

[image: Syntax nodes and their symbols]

With this you can build your own visualizer or maybe create a VISX to display it inside Visual Studio.

**Update**

After I wrote this, I find a [sample code in Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/blob/master/samples/CSharp/APISamples/SymbolsAndSemantics.cs#L125) that enumerate symbols in compilation.

Check also [GetAllFieldAndMethodSymbolsInACompilation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/614299ff83da9959fa07131c6d0ffbc58873b6ae/src/Samples/CSharp/APISampleUnitTests/FAQ.cs#L560) and [TraverseAllExpressionsInASyntaxTreeUsingAWalker](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/614299ff83da9959fa07131c6d0ffbc58873b6ae/src/Samples/CSharp/APISampleUnitTests/FAQ.cs#L637). 
Keep in mind that for complete solution you need to track also referenced assemblies.

Comment: Seems very useful. Though I don't get which visual tool you are using there to see the tree. It seems like one available while debugging in VS...

Comment: Very useful indeed Dudi! I have added another snippet which is a bit more generic to my question, it is very useful.

Comment: @Andry Thanks. I'm glad to help. The tool I'm using called [OzCode](http://www.oz-code.com/) and this specific feature called [LINQ debugging](http://o.oz-code.com/LINQ_EAP). And indeed it's for debugging in VS. It's a wonderful tool.

Answer (score 3):

The `SemanticModel` is merely a bridge between the syntax and symbols, it allows you to query parts of the syntax for symbols. The symbols, however, are all available from the `Compilation`. `Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName` is your friend in that regard.